# Voltage divider and LED

Tags: led, voltage-divider

I want to measure voltage presence when an LED lights up (i.e. the `IC_Output` goes LOW, LED is common anode).

The `-Ve` of LED is connected using a 1k resistor to the output of an IC and `+Ve` to VCC.

- Instead of adding a separate voltage divider, can I just add one resistor in series with the 1k resistor?
- How will this affect the brightness of the LED?

***original circuit:***

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feYh5Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

***modified circuit:***

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpJB4f.png)</sup>

Comment: Please draw schematics using the schematic editor of what and how you want to measure.

Comment: Are you sure about Vcc? And are you using a multi-coloured LED? For a single coloured LED, common anode does not make any sense... Anyway, the LED will influence the voltage divider in a very non-linear way. Better seperate the voltage divider and the LED and its serial resistor.

Comment: @Huisman, The led is a custom made 7 segment display. Here I have mentioned only one of its segment. By using voltage divider, I only want to measure high and low states, not the actual voltage so slight variations are not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Based on what you have drawn**

It seems that you want to measure the forward voltage, V<sub>f</sub> of the LED segments. Since your LED segment cathodes are connected to ground you only need to measure the anode voltage with your ADC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdgdtq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Measuring the forward voltage, V<sub>f</sub>, of an LED.*

**Based on what you have written**

> I want to measure voltage presence when an led lights up (i.e. the ic_output goes LOW, led is common anode).
>   The -ve of led is connected using a 1k resistor to the output of an IC and +ve to VCC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foy299.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Measurement for a common anode LED.*

This assumes that the LED anode is at the same voltage as the ADC V<sub>max</sub>.

- Turn the LED off by switching the GPIO high or disabling it.
- Measure the ADC voltage. This should be close to 1023 counts (on a 10-bit ADC).
- Turn the LED on by switching the GPIO low.
- Measure the ADC voltage.
- Subract reading 2 from reading 1. The result is the V<sub>f</sub>. Convert that from counts to volts.

Comment: What difference does a resistor make when it is in parallel with a led? i.e how will the brightness of led get affected by R2 in the 2nd circuit mentioned in the question ?

Comment: It will shunt current away from the LED resulting in dimmer LED and wasted power. You would only do it if you had a good reason such as you couldn't vary R1 in your circuit, for example.